# How to scrape links & the links display text using BS4 into a dictionary

Tags: html, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to scrape links like `<a href="http://www.example.com/default.html">Example`
I'd like to load them into a dictionary as `{Example:link}` where the link has the HTML tags stripped and is like the link someone would click.

I know how to get the links, I'm just not sure how to keep the links connected to the displayed text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, if you are able to extract `href` values, making a dictionary to map texts to links is a matter of a few extra things you need: making a [dictionary](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries) and [getting a text of an element](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#get-text). And, as you get the links and texts from the same element, you may use a *dictionary comprehension*.

Working example:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = """
<div>
    <a href="https://google.com">Google</a>
    <a href="https://stackoverflow.com">Stackoverflow</a>
</div>
"""


soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
print({
    a.get_text(strip=True): a["href"]
    for a in soup.find_all("a")
})
```

Prints:

```
{
    'Google': 'https://google.com', 
    'Stackoverflow': 'https://stackoverflow.com'
}
```